# Using Jquery to write html of Div based off of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently in the process of making a simple web based calculator. I'm having trouble assigning the value of my buttons to the "screen" area where I want to show the value of the number that was just pressed. I can get the value into a javascript variable, but when I attempt to write it into the screen area it is always coming up as undefined.

Here is my code:

```
$(".numbers").click(function(){
    currentValue = ($(this).val());
    $("#screen").html(function(){
        return "<p> " + currentValue.toString() + "</p>";
    })
    });
```

The problem seems to be that the code is getting run twice, but only when I have it set to return this (if I use return "test" it works perfectly).

Comment: try `$("#screen").html(function(){
        return "<p> " + currentValue.toString() + "</p>";
    }())` I guess anonymous function need to be executed to return required string!

Comment: Or this : `$("#screen").html("<p> " + currentValue + "</p>");` (Numbers are converted to strings when you concatenate them to strings - or when you use `.html()`).

Comment: @blex, Yeah..There is no point having anonymous function as an argument..

Comment: It depends on the task (maybe some calculation is needed inside this anonymous function). With the bit of code we have here, it seems to not be needed, but your solution should work if that's the case. @jasnonaz please show you HTML, or even better, the minimal amount of code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks. No luck on either of those. It seems that the function might be running twice, as when I log currentValue I get 1 (which is what I want) then an empty string. The script is definitely only in there once though.

Comment: @blex, Yeah...I thought it that way too..But if that is not the case, he should go simple way!

Comment: I think the OP and commenters have forgotton that `.html()` used as it is will overwrite the calculators screen everytime a number is pressed! You need to be including the current screen's content with your new number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you have provided, I believe this is all you need:

```
$(".numbers").click(function() {
    currentValue = $(this).val();
    $("#screen").html("<p> " + currentValue + "</p>")
});
```

I also believe that instead of using `.html()`, you should be using `append()` or use input box for the screen and use `.val()`. How you have it, using `.html`, you are overwriting the screen every time a number is pressed. You can still use `.html()` for this but you have to concatenate the orignal screen value with the new button number:

```
$('#screen').html($('#screen').html() + currentValue);
```

but it's better to use `.append()`:

```
$('#screen').append(currentValue);
```

Have a look at this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hk3ftbpz/) that uses an input box:

```
<input type="text" id="screen"></input>

<button class="numbers" value="1">1</button>
<button class="numbers" value="2">2</button>
<button class="numbers" value="3">3</button>

$(".numbers").on('click', function() {
    var $s = $('#screen');
    $s.val($s.val() + $(this).val())
});
```

Each time a number is pressed, it adds it to the end of the currently string of numbers, instead of overwriting everything.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your code working, show us your html.

```js
$(".numbers").on("click", function(){
    currentValue = $(this).val();
    $("#screen").html("<p> " + currentValue + "</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="numbers" value="2">Click me</button>
<div id="screen"></div>
```

Comment: Use the code snippet editor to post HERE instead of trying to cheat link codeless to JSFiddle.